# Using lira data, how do you write the conditional branch in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have three pictures, A.png, B.png and C.png, which I would like to show it on my tableview accessory area. I have record the category data A, B and C in my Lita database. I wanted to show different pictures for different categories. So I wrote the below code in the cellforrowatindexpath section.

```
    if (category.table = @"A"){
    accessoryView = A.png
    }else if (category.table = @"B"){
    accessoryView = B.png
    }else{
    accessoryView = C.png}
```

However, all the picture that shows on accessoryView is A.png.
What did I do wrong?
How could I fix this to show the pictures' properly.

I will be really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: On second thought, it is not a duplicate: Your code *assigns* a new value with `=`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help!
I had the same problem as the question you have indicated for me.
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy/paste this code fragment ? Cause string comparison are made this way in objective-C :

```
if ([category.table isEqualToString:@"A"])
{
  // do something
}
```

Other question : what class is your accessoryView ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply.
I have fixed my code, and it worked.
Thank you very much for your help.